# $f(x)=\max|x_i|, f(Ax)=f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \Rightarrow A^m=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

> Let $f(x) = \max|x_i|, \forall x=(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a matrix $A \in M_n[\mathbb{R}]$ such that $f(Ax)=f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
>   Prove that $\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}^+, A^m=I $.

Here my attempts:
Suppose $A = [a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$ and I choose $x = \{e_1=(1, 0, \dots, 0), e_2=(0, 1, \dots, 0), ..., e_n=(0, 0, \dots, 1)\}$ so that $f(Ae_i)=\max a_i=f(e_i)=1$ which means maximum absolute value of each column of $A$ is $1$.
Can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition $f(Ax)\equiv f(x)$ is equivalent to $\|Ax\|_\infty\equiv\|x\|_\infty$. Therefore it implies that:

1. $\|Ae_j\|_\infty=1$ for every $j$.
2. $\|A\|_\infty=\max_{x\ne0}\frac{\|Ax\|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty}=1$. But it is also known that $\|A\|_\infty=\max_{i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|$. Therefore $\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|\le1$ for every $i$.

It follows that the *entrywise* absolute value of $A$ is a permutation matrix. Let $\ell$ be the least common multiple of the cycle lengths in the permutation. Then $A^\ell$ is equal to a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are equal to $\pm1$. Hence $A^{2\ell}=I$.

Comment: Nice. (Injectivity is used implicitly in as far as I can tell to conclude that $A$ is a permutation.)

Comment: Can you please expand on how you got (2)? I don't understand where the equivalence for the entries of $A$ comes from.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat This is a well-known equivalent definition of the induced maximum norm. On one hand we have
$$\|Ax\|_\infty = \max_i|\sum_ja_{ij}x_j| \le (\max_i\sum_j|a_{ij}|)\|x\|_\infty.$$
On the other hand, suppose the maximum of $\sum_j|a_{ij}|$ occurs on row $k$. When $x$ is the transpose of sign vector of row $i$ of $A$, we have
$$\|Ax\|_\infty\ge|a_{k\ast}x|=\sum_j|a_{kj}|=\max_i\sum_j|a_{ij}|=\max_i\sum_j|a_{ij}|\|x\|_\infty.$$

Comment: @user1551, Sorry, one thing that I don't understand why we can conclude that $A$ is permutation matrix for example, let
$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&1\\1&-1&1\\1&-1&1\end{pmatrix}

Comment: @TrungNguyen Your example will not work. The absolute row sum for the first row, e.g., is equal to $3$, which is greater than $1$. This contradicts the observation in item 2 in my answer.

Comment: oh sorry :'( that was my bad. Thank you very much :D.